# Efficiently unpivot partitioned table on Teradata Vantage

Tags: teradata

I am trying to build a view to unpivot a large table with multiple hundred million rows efficiently, i.e. convert the table from a wide format with many columns to a long format. The system is Teradata Vantage 16.20.

The source table has the following structure:

```sql
CREATE MULTISET TABLE my_table (
  event_id        BIGINT,        -- a surrogate primary key
  event_date      DATE,          -- used for partitioning
  event_timestamp TIMESTAMP(6),  -- timestamp used for analysis
  value_001       INTEGER,       -- value nr. 1 used for analysis
  value_002       INTEGER,
  value_003       INTEGER,
  value_004       INTEGER,
  value_005       INTEGER,
  value_006       INTEGER,
  value_007       INTEGER,
  value_008       INTEGER,
  value_009       INTEGER,
  value_010       INTEGER,
  value_011       INTEGER,
  value_012       INTEGER,
  value_013       INTEGER,
  value_014       INTEGER,
  value_015       INTEGER,
  value_016       INTEGER,
  value_017       INTEGER,
  value_018       INTEGER,
  value_019       INTEGER,
  value_020       INTEGER        -- value nr. 20 used for analysis
  )
PRIMARY INDEX ( event_id )
PARTITION BY RANGE_N(event_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2025-12-31' EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY );
```

The source table is partitioned by `event_date` to allow efficient queries for small date ranges, e.g. `WHERE event_date BETWEEN DATE '2021-01-01' AND DATE '2021-01-02'`.
The query result should have 20 rows per row of `my_table`, each containing the value from one of the `value_xx` columns of `my_table`.

To unpivot the table, I use the following query:

```sql
WITH
input_data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM my_table
  WHERE (1=1)
--     AND event_date BETWEEN DATE '2021-01-01' AND DATE '2021-01-02'  -- FILTER AT POSITION 1
)

SELECT
    event_id
  , event_date
  , seqnum
  , val
FROM TD_UNPIVOT(
    ON (SELECT * FROM input_data)
    USING
        VALUE_COLUMNS('val')
        UNPIVOT_COLUMN('seqnum')
        COLUMN_LIST('value_001','value_002','value_003','value_004','value_005','value_006','value_007','value_008','value_009','value_010','value_011','value_012','value_013','value_014','value_015','value_016','value_017','value_018','value_019','value_020')
        COLUMN_ALIAS_LIST('001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008','009','010','011','012','013','014','015','016','017','018','019','020')
    ) t
WHERE (1=1)
--  AND event_date BETWEEN DATE '2021-01-01' AND DATE '2021-01-02'  -- FILTER AT POSITION 2
;
```

When the date filter is activated (uncommented) at POSITION 1 in the code example, the query finishes in a few seconds. The explain plan shows that the partitions of my_table are used to filter data efficiently.

When the date filter is activated (uncommented) only at POSITION 2 in the code example, the query runs much longer and uses an order of magnitude more AMPCPUTime. The explain plan shows that all rows of my_table are processed by `TD_UNPIVOT`, i.e. partitioning is not used for data access. This is very inefficient for large source tables.

When I put this code into a view, the filter at POSITION 1 is not usable, because the date range would be hard-coded in the view logic. Filtering during view access (`SELECT ... FROM my_view WHERE event_date...`) leads to inefficient processing similar to the filter at POSITION 2.
I also tried `UNPIVOT` instead of `TD_UNPIVOT`, with the same result.

Is there a way to help the query planner to propagate the filtering via the unpivot operation to the source table access? With other, much more complicated analytical queries but without `TD_UNPIVOT`, this usually works quite well.

Comment: Serious guess here, but what happens if you comment it out in the CTE and the unpivot where, and add it like so:  `FROM TD_UNPIVOT ( ON (SELECT * FROM INPUT_DATA WHERE DATE ...`

Comment: @Andrew filtering only within `FROM TD_UNPIVOT ( ON (SELECT * FROM INPUT_DATA WHERE event_date ...` uses partitioning successfully in the same way the filter at POSITION 1 does. In fact, the whole CTE `input_data` can be eliminated this way. However, this would still lead to a hard-coded date range in the unpivoting view I am trying to build.

Comment: Oh, you must be trying to create a view on the unpivot.  I thought you were trying to create a view to eliminate the CTE.  That's what I get for answering questions on Monday morning...